# Disabling double-tap to edit on Google Docs

Tags: google-drive

I frequently use Google Docs for school revision on-the-go, and I have to scroll down pages of course material when reading. Sometimes, I accidentally double-tap the page and this triggers the app to go into editing mode; this brings up the keyboard as well and is quite vexing, the only way to switch back to viewing mode is to either press the <kbd>◄</kbd> (back) button or the tick symbol on the top-left corner.

I can't find the setting of this in Google Drive and in Google Docs, I searched the Internet and found nothing.

How do I disable this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As of 20-07-2017, this feature is not available at this point in time.**